# How to schedule multiple cron workflows in temporal?

Tags: go, cron, temporal-workflow

Considering an array of strings as input, my aim is to schedule cron jobs for each. I have tried creating custom workflow options and executing the same, for each iteration of input. Following this only the first cron workflow gets scheduled while other cron jobs wait indefinetely.

```
    for ind , sid := range ss_ids {
        var cronScheduleStr string
        if ind == 0 {
            cronScheduleStr = "* * * * *"
        }
        if ind == 1 {
            cronScheduleStr = "2 * * * *"
        }
        workflowID := "cron_" + sid
        workflowOptions := client.StartWorkflowOptions{
            ID:           workflowID,
            TaskQueue:    "cron",
            CronSchedule: cronScheduleStr,
        }

        we, err := c.ExecuteWorkflow(context.Background(), workflowOptions, cron.SampleCronWorkflow,sid)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln("Unable to execute workflow", err)
        }
        log.Println("Started workflow", "WorkflowID", we.GetID(), "RunID", we.GetRunID())
    }
```

Apart from this I have tried child workflows in the same manner, but that also schedules only the first cron child workflow. It would be very kind, if someone can help out.

Comment: Check the value of "sid". My guess is that you are trying to start another workflow with the same WorkflowID.

Answer (score 2):

If `ss_ids` are unique, the first one should run every minute, the second one should run at the second minute of every hour, and the rest will have `CronSchedule: ''`.